# webapp doesnt start after spring-boot update to 1.3.1

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot, h2

I hope you can help me with this problem and couldn't find a solution.
I am working on a Webapplication with gradle 2.4, Java 8, Spring-boot and a H2-DB. We started with Spring-Boot 1.2.2 a while ago and decided to update Spring-Boot to 1.3.1. But with this Version the Server doesnt start anymore. It throws a NullPointerException when I start the Project (gradle bootRun)

```
2016-01-14 17:39:22.472 ERROR 8304 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.onApplicationEvent(DataSourceInitializer.java:100) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.onApplicationEvent(DataSourceInitializer.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:163) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:136) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:119) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerListeners(AbstractApplicationContext.java:809) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:535) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:764) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:357) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
at com.infinit.organization.config.Application.main(Application.java:46) [main/:na]
```

The build.gradle:

```
buildscript {

// The buildscript closure is executed at the beginning of gradle's configuration phase.
// It defines dependencies on gradle plugins that are used in the remaining configuration phase
// and in the execution phase.
// Note that spring-boot registers a custom Gradle ResolutionStrategy that allows to omit version numbers
// when declaring dependencies. Only the plugin version must be set.
ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.3.1.RELEASE'
}

// repositories used to resolve gradle plugins
repositories {
    maven { url "http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/"}
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/infinit/infinit-opensource" }
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/letteral/opensource" }
    maven { url 'https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/plugins-releases'}
}


// dependent gradle plugins
dependencies {
    classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}"
    classpath "net.saliman:gradle-cobertura-plugin:2.3.0"
    classpath "com.letteral:letteral-gradle-plugin:0.0.5"
}

}

// repositories used for satisfying project's configuration dependencies (e.g. compile, runtime)
repositories {
maven { url "http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/"}
mavenCentral()
maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" } // cobertura snapshots
maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/infinit/infinit-opensource" }
maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/letteral/opensource" }
maven { url 'https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/plugins-releases'}
}

// plugins needed in the build process
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'net.saliman.cobertura'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'letteral'
apply from: 'gensrc.gradle'
apply from: 'liquibase.gradle'

// check coverage limits locally with command '../gradlew cobertura coberturaCheck'
cobertura {
coberturaVersion = '2.1.1' // cobertura 2.1.x depends on asm-5 required for Java 8
coverageCheckHaltOnFailure = true // fail if coverage is below limits
coverageIgnoreTrivial = true // ignore simple getters and setters
coverageCheckBranchRate = 0 // minimum acceptable branch coverage rate (percent) needed by each class
coverageCheckLineRate = 0 // minimum acceptable line coverage rate (percent) needed by each class
coverageCheckTotalBranchRate = 50 // minimum acceptable branch coverage rate (percent) needed by the whole project
coverageCheckTotalLineRate = 50 // minimum acceptable line coverage rate (percent) needed by the whole project

coverageCheckRegexes = [
        // more fine grained limits per package
        [regex: 'com.infinit.atobcarry.config.*', branchRate: 0, lineRate: 0],
        [regex: 'com.infinit.atobcarry.entity.*', branchRate: 0, lineRate: 0]
]
//exclude the fixture files in order to get a realistic view of the coverage
coverageExcludes = [
        '.*\\.DevelopmentFixtures.*',
        '.*\\.Fixtures.*'
]
}
letteral {
username = 'username'
password = 'pass'
organization = 'org'
repos = files('mail')
apiUrl = 'http://letteral-dev.elasticbeanstalk.com/api'
}

configurations {
webapp  // configuration used to hold the build result of the client project
}

dependencies {
// spring boot dependencies
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket"
compile "org.springframework:spring-context-support"
compile "org.springframework:spring-messaging"

//compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")

// modelmapper
compile "org.modelmapper.extensions:modelmapper-spring:0.7.3"

// swagger
compile "com.mangofactory:swagger-springmvc:1.0.0"

// database dependencies
compile 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.190'
//    runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4-1201-jdbc41'

// liquibase
runtime 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.3.2'

// Joda
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.7'
compile 'org.jadira.usertype:usertype.spi:3.2.0.GA'
compile 'org.jadira.usertype:usertype.core:3.2.0.GA'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda';

// Apache commons
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'

// java melody dependencies
compile 'net.bull.javamelody:javamelody-core:1.55.0'
runtime 'com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.4.8'
runtime 'org.jrobin:jrobin:1.5.9'

// Atmosphere SSE / Websockets
compile 'org.atmosphere:atmosphere-runtime:2.2.6'

// Jackson
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core'
// letteral
compile 'com.letteral:letteral-client-java:0.0.17'

// tomtom
compile(group: 'com.tomtomworker.webfleet.connect', name: 'webfleet-connect-client', version: '1.1')

//google maps
compile 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.1.7'

//quartz
compile(group: 'org.quartz-scheduler', name: 'quartz', version: '2.2.1')
compile(group: 'org.quartz-scheduler', name: 'quartz-jobs', version: '2.2.1')

//itext pdf generation
compile('com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.5.6')
//xdocreport templating over freemarker
compile('fr.opensagres.xdocreport:xdocreport:1.0.3')
compile('fr.opensagres.xdocreport:fr.opensagres.xdocreport.template:1.0.3')
compile('fr.opensagres.xdocreport:fr.opensagres.xdocreport.template.freemarker:1.0.3')
//unfortuately we also need to include the velocity templates without using them
compile('fr.opensagres.xdocreport:fr.opensagres.xdocreport.template.velocity:1.0.3')
compile('fr.opensagres.xdocreport:fr.opensagres.xdocreport.converter.odt.odfdom:1.0.3')
//pdf signing with bouncy castle, must be 1.49 for now as itext 5.5.6 only supports BC 1.49
compile('org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.49')

//jts to create the tunnel
compile('com.vividsolutions:jts:1.13')
compile('org.geotools:gt-shapefile:14.0')
//compile('org.geotools:gt-swing:13.3')
compile('org.geotools:gt-epsg-hsql:14.0')

//javaxmail
compile 'javax.mail:mail:1.4.1'

//hazelcast
compile("com.hazelcast:hazelcast-all:3.5") {
    exclude group: 'org.freemarker'
}

// testing dependencies
testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
    // the following artifacts are excluded since spock is used:
    exclude group: 'org.mockito', module: 'mockito-core'
}

testCompile 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.1'
testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-spring:1.0-groovy-2.4'
testCompile 'com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:0.9.1'
testCompile 'cglib:cglib-nodep:3.1'

testCompile 'org.dbunit:dbunit:2.4.9'
testCompile 'com.github.springtestdbunit:spring-test-dbunit:1.2.1'

providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'

// web resources from client project
webapp project(path: ':atobcarry-client', configuration: 'webapp')
}

// configure the war task to deploy on conventional servlet container (e.g. tomcat)
war {
// let war task depend on webapp configuration
// hereby start relevant tasks in the client project;
// when the war task runs execute the closure
// hereby unzip the client project's build result
// and add it to the resources path of the war
// This folder is exposed as static content by spring boot.
dependsOn(configurations.webapp)
from { zipTree(configurations.webapp.singleFile) }
baseName = 'atobcarry'
//version =  '0.1.0'
}

// docker packaging requires a jar file that is configured similarly to the war
jar {
dependsOn(configurations.webapp)
from(zipTree(configurations.webapp.singleFile)) {
    into 'META-INF/resources'
}
baseName = 'atobcarry'
//version =  '0.1.0'
}
```

The application config:

```
mail.host=localhost
mail.from=organization@organization.de
organization.serverURL=http://localhost:8080
organization.enableTomTomTracking=false
organization.disableQuartzJobsInDebugMode=false
organization.restUrlTrackingPositions=http://localhost:8080/api/v1/trackingPositions/
organization.gracePeriodExpiredRequestsMinutes=1
organization.gracePeriodExpiredOffersMinutes=1
organization.keystorePath=security/atobcarry
organization.truststorePath=security/cacerts
organization.keyPassword=password
organization.keyAlias=organization
organization.keystorePassword=changeit
organization.pdfHashingAlgorithm=SHA-256
liquibase.changeLog=classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
liquibase.enabled=false
management.security.enabled:false
letteral.enabled=false
letteral.from=support@organization.com
letteral.apiKey=123456
letteral.apiUrl=http://letteral-dev.elasticbeanstalk.com/api
letteral.hoursTokenValid=24
letteral.organization=organization
letteral.repository=mail
letteral.release=not used
letteral.releaseVersion=not used
letteral.requestMailName=request
# google maps properties
googleMaps.directionsApiKey=xxxxx
googleMaps.mode=car
# for debugging letteral requests
# logging.level.org.apache.http.wire=DEBUG
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;MODE=PostgreSQL
spring.datasource.username=dbuser
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=true
#spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.open-in-view=true
spring.jpa.properties.jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes=true
spring.jpa.properties.jadira.usertype.databaseZone=UTC
spring.jpa.properties.jadira.usertype.javaZone=jvm
spring.jackson.dateFormat=yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'
spring.messages.basename=com/infinit/atobcarry/messages



multipart.maxFileSize=10Mb
```

That should be all relevant Information I hope. Please tell me if it isnt enought.

**update**: here are some more related files. What might be important: The Project contains 2 "subprojects": server and client. The Client is pure Javascript and works fine. The build.gradle above is the one from the server, I just added the main build.gradle and some other files as well.

application class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.infinit.atobcarry.repository")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ComponentScan("com.infinit.atobcarry")
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.infinit.atobcarry.entity"})
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class Application implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

    public final static String API_PREFIX = "/api/v1";

    public final static String FRONTEND_PREFIX = "/#";

    // As a default it is assumed that the document root is the app folder of the client project.
    // Relative to the root of the project this is located in the following path:
    private final static String CLIENT_DOCUMENT_ROOT = "../atobcarry-client/app";

    /**
     * An embedded container is started, when the application is run via the main method.
     * It can be started with the gradle command bootRun
     *
     * @param args start parameters
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        app.run(args);
    }

    /**
     * When running with an embedded servlet container additional configurations can be applied.
     *
     * @param container that is subject of the configuration
     */
    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {

        // The embedded servlet container shall use the resources from the client project
        configureDocumentRoot(container);

        // send charset in Content-Type response header to improve performance
        MimeMappings mappings = new MimeMappings(MimeMappings.DEFAULT);
        mappings.add("html", "text/html;charset=utf-8");
        container.setMimeMappings(mappings);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the document root to the resource folder of the client project if available.
     * This allows for instant reloading when developing the app.
     */
    private void configureDocumentRoot(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
        String documentRootPath = CLIENT_DOCUMENT_ROOT;
        File documentRoot = new File(documentRootPath);
        if (documentRoot.isDirectory() && documentRoot.canRead()) {
            container.setDocumentRoot(documentRoot);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show any configuration classes, which are doing something related to datasources? Also the main application class would be interesting.

Comment: That's very strange. It looks like `DataSourceInitializer` is being called before it's had a `DataSourceProperties` instance autowired into it. That shouldn't happen. Can you please share some code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I just added some more information. I will try to reproduce the error in a smaller project, as soon as I am done i will let you know!

Comment: I came back to this Problem yesterday and found something interesting, which seems to be the Problem: There were another (kind of hidden) Configuration file that configures Java Melody. The configuration added a dependency to DataSourceInitializer because the melody configuration should take place after Database Configuration. This doesn't seem to work after the upgrade from Spring boot 1.2.2 to Spring Boot 1.3.1 anymore and is causing the trouble i guess. Do you know how I can do this with spring boot 1.3.1? (See next comment for the configuration I found)

Comment: @Bean
    @DependsOn("dataSourceInitializer")
    SpringDataSourceBeanPostProcessor springDataSourceBeanPostProcessor() {
        return new SpringDataSourceBeanPostProcessor();
    }

Answer (score 0):

here are some more information:

this class might be interesting as well:

```
/**
 * Servlet 3.0+ environments allow to replace the web.xml file with a programmatic configuration.
 * <p/>
 * Created by owahlen on 01.01.14.
 */
public class Deployment extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    /**
     * This method is copied from SpringBootServletInitializer.
     * Only the registration of the ErrorPageFilter is omitted.
     * This was done since errors shall never be sent as redirects but as ErrorDto
     * @param servletContext
     * @return
     */
    protected WebApplicationContext createRootApplicationContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder();
        ApplicationContext parent = getExistingRootWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
        if (parent != null) {
            this.logger.info("Root context already created (using as parent).");
            servletContext.setAttribute(WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE, null);
            builder.initializers(new ParentContextApplicationContextInitializer(parent));
        }
        builder.initializers(new ServletContextApplicationContextInitializer(servletContext));
        builder.contextClass(AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext.class);
        builder = configure(builder);
        SpringApplication application = builder.build();
        if (application.getSources().isEmpty()
                && AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(getClass(), Configuration.class) != null) {
            application.getSources().add(getClass());
        }
        Assert.state(application.getSources().size() > 0,
                "No SpringApplication sources have been defined. Either override the "
                        + "configure method or add an @Configuration annotation");
        // Error pages are handled by the ExceptionHandlerController. No ErrorPageFilter is needed.
        // application.getSources().add(ErrorPageFilter.class);
        return run(application);
    }

    private ApplicationContext getExistingRootWebApplicationContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        Object context = servletContext.getAttribute(WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE);
        if (context instanceof ApplicationContext) {
            return (ApplicationContext) context;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

and another configuration - class:

```
@Configuration
public class H2Console {

    protected final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());


    /**
     * Define the H2 Console Servlet
     *
     * @return ServletRegistrationBean to be processed by Spring
     */
    @Bean(name= "h2servlet")
    public ServletRegistrationBean h2servletRegistration() {
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new WebServlet());
        registration.addInitParameter("webAllowOthers", "true"); // allow access from URLs other than localhost
        registration.addUrlMappings("/console/*");
        return registration;
    }
}
```

main build.gradle:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.asciidoctor:asciidoctor-gradle-plugin:1.5.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.asciidoctor.gradle.asciidoctor'

ext {
    applicationVersion = 'UNDEFINED'
    appBackend = null
}

asciidoctor {
    sourceDir = file('asciidoc')
    options = [
            doctype   : 'book',
            attributes: [
                    'source-highlighter': 'coderay',
                    toc                 : '',
                    idprefix            : '',
                    idseparator         : '-'
            ]
    ]
}

def defaultEnvironment() {
    def environment = ["PATH=${System.env.PATH}"]
    environment += "HOME=${System.env.HOME}"
    return environment
}

def execAsync(command, printStdOutput, dir, expectedOutput) {
    println("Starting async command $command")

    final CountDownLatch condition = new CountDownLatch(1)

    def commandEnvironment = defaultEnvironment()

    def proc = command.execute(commandEnvironment, new File(dir as String))
    Thread.start {
        try {
            proc.in.eachLine { line ->
                if (printStdOutput) {
                    println "$line"
                }
                if (expectedOutput != null && line?.contains(expectedOutput)) {
                    condition.countDown()
                }
            }
        }
        catch (ignored) {
        }
    }
    Thread.start {
        try {
            proc.err.eachLine { line ->
                if (printStdOutput) {
                    println line
                }
            }
        }
        catch (ignored) {
        }
    }
    return [proc, expectedOutput != null ? condition : null]
}


task startServer() {
    doLast {
        def condBackend
        (appBackend, condBackend) = execAsync(["./gradlew", "run"], true, "$projectDir", "Started Application")
        condBackend.await()
    }
}

task stopProcesses << {
    appBackend?.destroy()
}

task e2eReport(dependsOn: [startServer, ':atobcarry-client:clean', ':project-client:e2eTest'])
tasks.getByPath(':project-client:e2eTest').mustRunAfter(startServer)
stopProcesses.mustRunAfter(':project-client:e2eTest')
startServer.finalizedBy(stopProcesses)
e2eReport.finalizedBy(stopProcesses)
tasks.getByPath(':project-client:e2eTest').finalizedBy(stopProcesses)
task validate(dependsOn: [':project-client:grunt_default', ':project-server:cobertura', ':project-server:coberturaCheck'])
```

the settings.gradle:

```
// This file includes the gradle subprojects of project project
include 'project-server'           // REST webserver backend (WAR)
include 'project-client'           // AngularJS frontend (JAR)
include 'project-tracking'         // TomTom tracking server (WAR)
include 'project-tracking-commons' // Shared code between tracking and server
```

querydsl.graddle (from project-server)

```
configurations {
    // configuration to hold the build dependency on the querydsl generator
    querydslapt
}

String queryDslVersion = '3.5.1'
dependencies {
    querydslapt "com.mysema.querydsl:querydsl-apt:$queryDslVersion"
    compile "com.mysema.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:$queryDslVersion"
}

task generateQueryDSL(type: JavaCompile, group: 'build', description: 'Generate the QueryDSL query types.') {
    // only process entity classes and enums to avoid compilation errors from code that needs the generated sources
    source = fileTree('src/main/java/com/infinit/atobcarry/entity') + fileTree('src/main/java/com/infinit/project/enums')
    // include the querydsl generator into the compilation classpath
    classpath = configurations.compile + configurations.querydslapt
    options.compilerArgs = [
            "-proc:only",
            "-processor", "com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor"
    ]
    options.warnings = false
    // the compiler puts the generated sources into the gensrcDir
    destinationDir = gensrcDir
}

gensrc {
    // extend the gensrc task to also generate querydsl
    dependsOn generateQueryDSL
}
```

liquibase.graddle (from server)

```
configurations {
    liquibase
}

dependencies {
    liquibase 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.3.2'
    liquibase 'org.liquibase.ext:liquibase-hibernate4:3.5'
    // liquibase 'org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.14'
    liquibase 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1103-jdbc41'
    liquibase 'org.springframework:spring-beans'
    liquibase 'org.springframework:spring-orm'
    liquibase 'org.springframework:spring-context'
    liquibase 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot' // contains the SpringNamingStrategy
    liquibase 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final'
}

[
        'status'                 : 'Outputs count (list if --verbose) of unrun change sets.',
        'validate'               : 'Checks the changelog for errors.',
        'changelogSync'          : 'Mark all changes as executed in the database.',
        'changelogSyncSQL'       : 'Writes SQL to mark all changes as executed in the database to STDOUT.',
        'listLocks'              : 'Lists who currently has locks on the database changelog.',
        'releaseLocks'           : 'Releases all locks on the database changelog.',
        'markNextChangesetRan'   : 'Mark the next change set as executed in the database.',
        'markNextChangesetRanSQL': 'Writes SQL to mark the next change set as executed in the database to STDOUT.',
        'dropAll'                : 'Drops all database objects owned by the user. Note that functions, procedures and packages are not dropped (limitation in 1.8.1).',
        'clearChecksums'         : 'Removes current checksums from database. On next run checksums will be recomputed.',
        'generateChangelog'      : 'generateChangeLog of the database to standard out. v1.8 requires the dataDir parameter currently.',
        'futureRollbackSQL'      : 'Writes SQL to roll back the database to the current state after the changes in the changeslog have been applied.',
        'update'                 : 'Updates the database to the current version.',
        'updateSQL'              : 'Writes SQL to update the database to the current version to STDOUT.',
        'updateTestingRollback'  : 'Updates the database, then rolls back changes before updating again.',
        'diff'                   : 'Writes description of differences to standard out.',
        'diffChangeLog'          : 'Writes Change Log XML to update the base database to the target database to standard out.',
        'updateCount'            : 'Applies the next <liquibaseCommandValue> change sets.',
        'updateCountSql'         : 'Writes SQL to apply the next <liquibaseCommandValue> change sets to STDOUT.',
        'tag'                    : 'Tags the current database state with <liquibaseCommandValue> for future rollback',
        'rollback'               : 'Rolls back the database to the state it was in when the <liquibaseCommandValue> tag was applied.',
        'rollbackToDate'         : 'Rolls back the database to the state it was in at the <liquibaseCommandValue> date/time.',
        'rollbackCount'          : 'Rolls back the last <liquibaseCommandValue> change sets.',
        'rollbackSQL'            : 'Writes SQL to roll back the database to the state it was in when the <liquibaseCommandValue> tag was applied to STDOUT.',
        'rollbackToDateSQL'      : 'Writes SQL to roll back the database to the state it was in at the <liquibaseCommandValue> date/time to STDOUT.',
        'rollbackCountSQL'       : 'Writes SQL to roll back the last <liquibaseCommandValue> change sets to STDOUT.'
].each { String taskName, String taskDescription ->
    String prefixedTaskName = 'dbm' + taskName.capitalize()
    task(prefixedTaskName, type: JavaExec) { JavaExec task ->
        initLiquibaseTask(task)
        args += taskName
        String liquibaseCommandValue = project.properties.get("liquibaseCommandValue")
        if (liquibaseCommandValue) {
            args += liquibaseCommandValue
        }
    }
}

void initLiquibaseTask(JavaExec task) {
    String changeLogFile = 'src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml'
    task.main = 'liquibase.integration.commandline.Main'
    task.classpath = configurations.liquibase + sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    task.args = [
            // "--logLevel=debug",
            "--changeLogFile=${changeLogFile}",
            "--url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:15432/roject",
            "--username=project",
            "--password=project",
            "--referenceUrl=hibernate:spring:com.infinit.atobcarry?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect&hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringNamingStrategy&hibernate.enhanced_id=true",
    ]
    task.group = 'liquibase'
}
```

jreleaseinfo.gradle

```
configurations {
    // configuration to hold the build dependency on the jreleaseinfo ant task
    jreleaseinfo
}

dependencies {
    jreleaseinfo 'ch.oscg.jreleaseinfo:jreleaseinfo:1.3.0'
}

task generateJReleaseInfo(group: 'build', description: 'Generate the VersionInfo class.') { Task task ->
    Map<String, ?> parameters = [
            buildKey: project.hasProperty('buildKey') ? project.buildKey : '',
            buildResultKey: project.hasProperty('buildResultKey') ? project.buildResultKey : '',
            buildNumber: project.hasProperty('buildNumber') ? project.buildNumber : '',
            buildResultsUrl: project.hasProperty('buildResultsUrl') ? project.buildResultsUrl : '',
            gitBranch: project.hasProperty('gitBranch') ? project.gitBranch : '',
            gitCommit: project.hasProperty('gitCommit') ? project.gitCommit : ''
    ]
    task.inputs.properties(parameters)
    task.inputs.property('version', project.version)
    task.outputs.file( new File(gensrcDir, 'com/infinit/atobcarry/config/VersionInfo.java') )
    task.doLast {
        // gradle properties that can be passed to the JReleaseInfoAntTask task
        ant.taskdef(name: 'jreleaseinfo', classname: 'ch.oscg.jreleaseinfo.anttask.JReleaseInfoAntTask', classpath: configurations.jreleaseinfo.asPath)
        ant.jreleaseinfo(targetDir: gensrcDir, className: 'VersionInfo', packageName: 'com.infinit.atobcarry.config', version: project.version) {
            parameters.each { String key, String value ->
                parameter(name: key, type: 'String', value: value)
            }
        }
    }
}

gensrc {
    // extend the gensrc task to also generate JReleaseInfo
    dependsOn generateJReleaseInfo
}
```

gensrc.gradle

```
// register directory where generated sources are located with the project
ext.gensrcDir = file('src/main/generated')

// create a wrapper task for source generation that the generators can depend upon
task gensrc(group: 'build', description: 'Execute all tasks that generate source code.')

// include the source code generators
apply from: 'querydsl.gradle'
apply from: 'jreleaseinfo.gradle'

// add the gensrcDir to the sourceSets
sourceSets {
    generated
}
sourceSets.generated.java.srcDirs = [gensrcDir]

// extend the conventional compileJava task to also compile the generated sources
compileJava {
    dependsOn gensrc
    source gensrcDir
}

clean {
    delete gensrcDir
}
```

orm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd"
                 version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit-metadata>
        <persistence-unit-defaults>
            <entity-listeners>
                <entity-listener class="org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener"/>
            </entity-listeners>
        </persistence-unit-defaults>
    </persistence-unit-metadata>

</entity-mappings>
```